# Firestore orderBy with whereArrayContains shows results in emulator but not on device

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a situation on Android (java) where my firestore query is working on the emulator but not on device. If i drop either the whereArrayContains clause OR the orderBy clause it starts working again on device. Strangely enough also after running the solution with either of those off and then re-running it with them back on the query it will work from that point on (until complete stop/app uninstall and re-run)

There is nothing helpful im seeing in firebase console and ive also played with the setPersistenceEnabled setting and that does not fix the issue.

My firestore query:

```
Query query = mFirestore.collection("calls");
        query = query.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereArrayContains("driver",uid).limit(20);
```

My firestore db:

[image]

Firebase log if it helps:

2021-04-21 17:03:56.135 1812-2182/? D/WIFI_AWARE_FACTORY: got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=2363, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10361 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10361 RequestorPackageName: com.google.firebase.example.fireeats] ] with score 60 and providerId 5
2021-04-21 17:03:56.336 1812-2182/? D/WIFI_AWARE_FACTORY: got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=2364, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10361 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10361 RequestorPackageName: com.google.firebase.example.fireeats] ] with score 60 and providerId 5

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/mvnmwy/firestore_orderby_with_wherearraycontains_shows/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i needed an index in firestore for this query to work. Why it worked in the emulator and failed on the device still remains a mystery.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

After writing the querysnapshot result to log i finally saw that indexing error and link to create the index that is mentioned in the FS documentation which also states this should show up in the firebase console, for me it did not.

Doing this got me the query error:

```
QuerySnapshot result = query.get().getResult();
Log.w("result:", result.toString());
```